# MS Access SQL join problems in case of "recurring" query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, left-join, ms-access-2010

I'm facing an issue where we have 3 tables.
It should display if supplying warehouse does not have that item (deleted) or not even has a setup for however it should be the supplying warehouse according to source matrix.

Simplified layout should look like that.

Table **MainData**

- Field **ItemNo** - individual identifier, no duplicates (PK)
- Field **ItemType** - there's a certain selection, i have to filter some
  specific value.

Table **WarehouseData**

- Field **ItemNo** - related with MainData, but PK is combined with next field
- Field **ItemLocation** - give a specific location of such items described with ItemNo
- Field **ItemCategory** - need to join to SourceWHMatrix
- Field **ItemDeleted** - it's a char field (because of exported data), if the item is "deleted" the value is 'X', otherwise Null (not empty!)

Table **SourceWHMatrix**

- Field **ItemLocation** - first two fields are primary keys
- Field **ItemCategory**
- Field **SourceLocation** - it should give where the item will be delivered

I need to check the following:
If **ItemNo** belongs to certain **ItemType** (MainData table) *AND* **ItemDeleted** Is Null then whether this **ItemNo** is at **SourceLocation** (which is determined by **SourceWHMatrix** based on **ItemLocation** *AND* **ItemCategory**). Need to be listed all **ItemNo** which are "deleted" at **SourceLocation** (in this case in table **WarehouseData** field **ItemLocation** is checked for returned **SourceLocation** value) *OR* not even setupped for such location.

Note: In case of same **ItemNo** for different **ItemLocation**, **ItemCategory** not always match. And every **ItemLocation** has many different **ItemCategory** to determine the source warehouse.

I tried to many combinations of LEFT JOINs but it seems that somehow I cannot list those values that are not setup. (By creating a duplicate table of WarehouseData I was able to list deleted items at supplying warehouse.) Also I could do this in VBA with ADODB, but I want to keep everything in SQL code, and not even using custom functions. It's in Access 2010, running on its JET SQL engine.

This is the current query that doesn't work

```
SELECT MD.itemno, 
       MD.itemtype, 
       WD.itemlocation, 
       SMat.sourcelocation, --this could be empty
       WD.itemdeleted AS "SourceWHDelFlag" 
FROM   maindata AS MD 
       INNER JOIN (warehousedata AS WD 
                   INNER JOIN (sourcewhmatrix AS SMat 
                               LEFT JOIN wd 
                                      ON SMat.sourcelocation = WD.itemlocation) 
                           ON ( WD.itemlocation = SMat.itemlocation 
                                AND WD.itemcategory = SMat.itemcategory ) ) 
               ON MD.itemno = WD.itemno 
WHERE  ( MD.itemtype = 'Value1' 
          OR MD.itemtype = 'Value2' )
```

This what I can came up with after further thinking. However the queries running for 20 mins now on my i5. So this is not optimal, and also when I could check some pre-results of Access it seemed that adding the alias' statement to where clause causing a bug, as no longer filters properly on other fields within the same where clause. So this is my "solution":

```
SELECT MD.ItemNo,
       MD.ItemType
       WD.itemlocation, 
       SMat.sourcelocation, --this could be empty
       (SELECT WD.ItemDeleted FROM WD WHERE WD.ItemNo = MD.ItemNo) AS "SourceWHDelFlag"
FROM MainData AS MD INNER JOIN (WarehouseData AS WD
                                LEFT JOIN SourceWHMatrix AS SMat
                                       ON (WD.ItemLocation = SMat.ItemLocation
                                           AND WD.ItemCategory = SMat.ItemCategory))
                                ON MD.ItemNo = WD.ItemNo
WHERE (MD.ItemType = 'Value1' OR MD.ItemType = 'Value2')
      AND WD.ItemDeleted Is Null
      AND WD.ItemCategory Is Not Null
      AND WD.ItemCategory Not Like '##' -- This is another filter value, and it seems to be buggy
                                        -- with SELECT clause in WHERE statement
      AND (SELECT WD.ItemDeleted FROM WD WHERE WD.ItemNo = MD.ItemNo) Is Not Null
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

**UPDATE**
I did some VBA, this code is actually working. I commented all the necessary infos in the code, but it's still freaking slow. (If you have an idea to make it significantly faster to run in reasonable time frame, I'm open for it.) 200 records took around 10 mins, therefore it should take 15 hours to run on 16-17 thousand records. I can do this in Excel much faster in Excel with some VLookup...

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

'initialize variables
Dim connDB As ADODB.Connection
Dim filtRecSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim tmpRecSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim tmpLineText As String
Dim tmpCounter As Integer
Dim filePath As String
Dim tmpFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim tmpStream As TextStream
Dim startTime, endTime As Double

'set values
Set connDB = New ADODB.Connection
Set connDB = CurrentProject.Connection
Set filtRecSet = New ADODB.Recordset
Set tmpRecSet = New ADODB.Recordset
filePath = "C:\data\output.txt"
Set tmpStream = tmpFSO.CreateTextFile(filePath, True)

startTime = Now()

'this is a test database
'I previously deleted all not required MD.ItemType to test speed of SQL queries
'it's the reason for no filtering on MD.ItemType

'open base recordset, which are not deleted (WD.ItemDeleted)
'and belong tospecific MD.ItemType values
'and can match certain filters on WD.ItemCategory
With filtRecSet
    .ActiveConnection = connDB
    .Source = "SELECT MD.ItemNo, WD.ItemLocation, MD.ItemType, WD.ItemCategory, SMat.SourceLocation FROM MainData As MD INNER JOIN (WarehouseData As WD LEFT JOIN SourcwWHMatrix As SMat ON (WD.ItemLocation = SMat.ItemLocation AND WD.ItemCategory = SMat.ItemCategory)) ON MD.ItemNo = WD.ItemNo WHERE WD.ItemCategory Is Not Null AND WD.ItemCategory Not Like '[0-9][0-9]' AND WD.ItemDeleted Is Null"
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adUseClient
End With
'RecordCount: 16610

'open control recordset for all appropiate MD.ItemType
With tmpRecSet
    .ActiveConnection = connDB
    .Source = "SELECT MD.ItemNo, WD.ItemLocation, MD.ItemType, WD.ItemCategory, SMat.SourceLocation FROM MainData As MD INNER JOIN (WarehouseData As WD LEFT JOIN SourcwWHMatrix As SMat ON (WD.ItemLocation = SMat.ItemLocation AND WD.ItemCategory = SMat.ItemCategory)) ON MD.ItemNo = WD.ItemNo"
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adUseClient
    .Filter = adFilterNone
End With
'RecordCount: 138713

filtRecSet.Open
'tmp variable to see how many records have been processed
tmpCounter = 1
If Not filtRecSet.EOF Then
    'select first record
    filtRecSet.MoveFirst
    Do While Not filtRecSet.EOF
        'find SourceLocation
        tmpRecSet.Filter = "MATNR = '" & filtRecSet(0).Value & "' AND WERKS = '" & filtRecSet(5).Value & "'"
        tmpRecSet.Open
        'check how many records in recordset; there should not be more than one, that's why it considered as error
        If tmpRecSet.RecordCount = 1 Then
            tmpRecSet.MoveFirst
            tmpLineText = filtRecSet(0).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(1).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(2).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(3).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(4).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(5).Value & "|" & tmpRecSet(3).Value
        ElseIf tmpRecSet.RecordCount > 1 Then
            tmpLineText = "ERROR"
        'in case EOF is True -> no records
        Else
            tmpLineText = filtRecSet(0).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(1).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(2).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(3).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(4).Value & "|" & filtRecSet(5).Value & "|"
        End If
        Debug.Print "Record no.: " & tmpCounter
        'write out text file
        tmpStream.WriteLine tmpLineText
        filtRecSet.MoveNext
        tmpRecSet.Close
        tmpCounter = tmpCounter + 1
    Loop
End If

tmpStream.Close
endTime = Now()

Debug.Print "Elapsed time: " & CStr((endTime - startTime) * 24 * 60 * 60) & " seconds."

End Sub
```

Comment: Its likely that some of your where conditions should be put in the LEFT JOIN. Regrettably the textual description of your requirements are too difficult for me to parse. For instance the `then whether` is hard to follow. Perhaps you can [edit] your question to make this a bit more concise. For example a bulleted list.

Comment: Thanks for your response conrad.

Comment: It should look like that, hope i didn't messed up anything in the rush:
SELECT MD.ItemNo, MD.ItemType, WD.ItemLocation , SMat.SourceLocation -> this could be empty, WD.ItemDeleted AS "SourceWHDelFlag" -> this should come from WD table when checked for SourceLocation = ItemLocation
 FROM MainData AS MD INNER JOIN (WarehouseData AS WD INNER JOIN (SourceWHMatrix AS SMat LEFT JOIN WD ON SMat.SourceLocation = WD.ItemLocation) ON (WD.ItemLocation = SMat.ItemLocation AND WD.ItemCategory = SMat.ItemCategory) ON MD.ItemNo = WD.ItemNo.

Comment: WHERE (MD.ItemType = 'Value1' OR MD.ItemType = 'Value2') AND WD.ItemDeleted Is Null AND (SourceWHDelFlag Is Not Null OR SMat.SourceLocation Is Null)

Comment: I updated your question to include your sql from the comments. This way others may see it and help. That said, why not make this `INNER JOIN (sourcewhmatrix AS SMat ` a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: thanks for your kind help. i also added some code to it.

Comment: You might want to try changing `AND (SELECT WD.ItemDeleted FROM WD WHERE WD.ItemNo = MD.ItemNo) Is Not Null` to `AND EXISTs (SELECT * FROM WarehouseData WD2 Where WD2.ItemDeleted is not null and WD2.ItemNo = MD.ItemID)`

Comment: I just tested. It's still running extremely slow, I stopped the query as I go to bed soon. When I removed 'EXISTS' it's still running sloooooow. It doesn't finished in 5 mins, I stopped it as well. Also when Access started to display the results, it's still failing on neglecting the numbers in 'Not Like' expression. UPDATE: MD table is around 300.000, WD is around 500.000 records with at least 30 fields each. WD is around 300 mbytes.

Comment: I added some VBA code that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out some solution, yesterday's idea was almost good, however there were an issue about speed. Therefore I tried to set up some indexing on all these fields in my test database (I did not use this function, as I was also facing issues about 2 gbyte limitation of Access files, and wanted preserve all possible space). Besides I enforced referential integrity between **MD.ItemNo** and **WD.ItemNo**. Primary keys and relationships has been set up; indexing allows duplicates except on **MD.ItemNo**. The result is, it runs in a few seconds, and give back the correct result.

Now I just have to modify my import script to generate such XMLs that create indexing on necessary fields. It'll be also an issue as all fields are necessary, that's the reason behind the whole import script to skip two-third of them (total around 800 fields).

This speed up the running of VBA code as well, but still very very slow.

This is the SQL that works:

```
SELECT MD.ItemNo,
       MD.ItemType
       WD.ItemLocation, 
       WD.ItemDeleted
       SMat.SourceLocation, --this could be empty
       (SELECT WD.ItemDeleted
           FROM WD
           WHERE WD.ItemNo = MD.ItemNo
                 AND WD.ItemLocation = SMat.SourceLocation
       ) AS SourceDeleted
FROM MainData AS MD INNER JOIN (WarehouseData AS WD
                                LEFT JOIN SourceWHMatrix AS SMat
                                       ON (WD.ItemLocation = SMat.ItemLocation
                                           AND WD.ItemCategory = SMat.ItemCategory))
                                ON MD.ItemNo = WD.ItemNo
WHERE (MD.ItemType = 'Value1' OR MD.ItemType = 'Value2')
      AND WD.ItemDeleted Is Null
      AND WD.ItemCategory Is Not Null
      AND WD.ItemCategory Not Like '[0-9][0-9]' -- there's an issue about wildcards
      AND (SMat.SourceLocation Is Null -- to display not set up ItemNo on SourceLocation
           OR (SELECT WD.ItemDeleted
                  FROM WD
                  WHERE WD.ItemNo = MD.ItemNo
                        AND WD.ItemLocation = SMat.SourceLocation
              ) Is Not Null) -- check if ItemDeleted on SourceLocation
```